# How to get exact search using lucene

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene

When we searching like "prd gem". It returns all results names with prd gem.
but when we search only "prd", it returns all results with prd in it like prd,prd gem, prd time etc. Why not exact search now?

Following was code in picture:

```
luceneQuery = queryBuilder.phrase()
                .onField("productId")
                .andField("productName").andField("refId")
                .sentence(searchText)
                        .createQuery();
```

Exact search is working fine with the name having space in it like if i search "Prd Gem", it shows only one product with name "Prd Gem", but when i search only a word like "prd", exact search is not working, it shows all product like "prd","prd gem"

So what changes need to be done with above code to implement the same?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are "tokenizing" the data in the lucene index.

Lucene by default will try to break the strings into tokens in order to allow and speed up such searches.

I assume you are using the latest hibernate. Can you try to annotate the "productName" field with the following:

```
 @Field(name = "productName",  index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, norms = Norms.NO)
```

The "analyze = Analyze.no" part should disable this feature.